# mercurial : disable all the extensions from the command line

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

Is there a way for running mercurial without any external extension using a command line switch / environment variable?

For example, in this situation:

```
$ hg version --debug
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.3.3)
[...]
Enabled extensions:

  hggit             external
  hgremotebranches  external
  mq                internal
  rebase            internal
  shelve            internal
```

How can I accomplish:

```
$ hg --disable-all-extensions version --debug
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 4.3.3)
[...]
Enabled extensions:

  <empty>
```

I know I can disable individual extensions via `--config extensions.name=!`, but I need to nuke everything at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `hg help environment`:

```
HGRCPATH
        A list of files or directories to search for configuration files. Item
        separator is ":" on Unix, ";" on Windows. If HGRCPATH is not set,
        platform default search path is used. If empty, only the .hg/hgrc from
        the current repository is read.
```

So you can do:

```
HGRCPATH= hg version --debug
```

The mercurial developers encourage everyone to use this incantation in scripts to avoid having the meaning of mercurial commands depend on a user's configuration. See http://mozilla-version-control-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/hgmozilla/automation.html for more information from Mozilla about automating mercurial.